# Dynamically set controller name based upon directory structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui.router and I want to be able to have a function that selects the relevant controller based upon the directory structure or URL. Below is an example of what I currently have, where the controller for the index.main state is static:

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $state) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/index/main");

$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        abstract: true,
        url: "/index",
        templateUrl: "components/index/content.html",
    })
    .state('index.main', {
        controller: 'MainCtrl as controller',
        url: "/main",
        templateUrl: "components/index/main/main.html",
        data: { pageTitle: 'Main' }
    })
}
```

I just want the MainCtrl controller to be selected based upon it's path i.e:

```
    $stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        abstract: true,
        url: "/index",
        templateUrl: "components/index/content.html",
    })
    .state('index.main', {
        controller: function(){
            return 'MainCtrl'; // based on the path: components/index/main - this can be based on the state or the URL as well, it just has to follow a similar structure 
        },
        url: "/main",
        templateUrl: "components/index/main/main.html",
        data: { pageTitle: 'Main' }
    })
}
```

Where the returned statement from the function is based upon the current route's state or directory structure, it can be either because I will be keeping the same structure throughout the application.

Thanks in advance!!